The web-mode-hook I wrote in Emacs init.el is not applied by default
I wrote settings in the init.el
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))

(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  (setq web-mode-block-padding 0)
  )
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'my-web-mode-hook)

When a php file is opened in Emacs, it opens as web-mode, but the web-mode-block-padding setting is ignored.
Running M-x web-mode in that state will activate the web-mode-block-padding setting.

Why is the hook content not reflected in web-mode immediately after opening Emacs?
What can we do to reflect this from the beginning?

Emacs version is GNU Emacs 29.3
I am not familiar with init.el and do not know how to deal with this.

Are you on Windows or Linux or something else? Where exactly is your init.el file? From what you are describing, it's probably in a place that Emacs is not checking for an init file. See How Emacs finds your init file for details. You should probably ask this question (with all the additional details I ask above) on the Emacs SE. SO is for programming questions only.

Oh, sorry. I am trying it on Linux (Ubuntu). The placement of init.el is correct, and all configuration items except for my-web-mode-hook are loaded correctly. I will consider asking the question in a more appropriate place.

What happens if you start emacs (with your original init file, before you add the lines shown above) and then say M-: (require 'web-mode) - does that succeed?

The code looks correct, so my theory would be that something may be overwriting your settings. Try inserting a (print "hi") after the setq code and see if it appears in *Messages* buffer. If it does, then you'd need to try to reduce config to see what may be changing the variable.
